# C# update a table in database from a DataTable in c# object?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a DataTable in my code.
It's Like this

[image]

and in my database I have a Table Like this

[image]

first I order these two table order by `GroupId` asc
then I want to update the Second Table'column `Ticket` with the first Table `Number`.
I want to Join them througn RowNumber(order by GroupId)

how to write this? It seems easy to use linq.

```
DataTable dt1=myfirstDatatable;
DataTable dt2=SQLServerHelper.GetDataTable(sql);
```

so I want to update `dt2` with `dt1`, and wrote back to database.

Comment: If you are only ordering on GroupID - then you cannot guarantee the order of rows where the GroupID is not unique. So joining by Row Number is not guaranteed to give the same results each time.

Comment: If you are happy with the problem I stated above then see this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ecb6a83d-b9b0-4e64-8107-1ca8757fe58c/how-to-use-linq-to-join-multiple-datatables?forum=adodotnetdataset

Comment: the issue is like this.I have distribute some continuous seats to every group,it just need to give these seats to that group.It need't to carry about which seat to which people in that group